# Casting from int* to void*. What for?

Tags: c, casting, int, void

I'm learning C and I've found something like that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int* y) {
  int x = 1;
  *y = 2;
  y = &x;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int x = 3;
  int* x_ptr = &x;
  printf("Value before call: %d\n", x);
  printf("Pointer before function call: %p\n",(void*)x_ptr);
  func(x_ptr);
  printf("Value after call: %d\n", x);
  printf("Pointer after function call: %p\n",(void*)x_ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

I don't know why (void*)x_ptr int* casting is used.
Why use int* to void* casting?
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I copy from another question:

Casting to `void *` for arguments to the `%p` format in a variadic function is actually required by the language standard. – Jens Apr 17 '11 at 10:54

[Printing pointers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197757/printing-pointers-in-c#comment6503368_197780)

Comment: For a good answer, you should at least provide a reference to the corresponding section(s) in the standard.